# Conditional copying properties and values from one array of objects to another

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

Got two arrays of objects and my goal is to check if the value under property *id* from **array1** matches the value under the property *categoryId* of **array2**. When find a match want to add the missing property *amount* to the relevant member of **array1** or create a new array containing all the properties and values I need - *id, name, amount*

Here are the two arrays:

```
const array1 = [{
  id: 8,
  name: 'Online Shopping',
},
{
  id: 12,
  name: 'Subscriptions',
},
{
 id: 5,
  name: 'Patreon donations',
}]
```

and

```
const array2 = [
{
  expence: {
    amount: -66.66,
  },
  categoryId: 5,
},
{
  expence: {
    amount: 100018.85,
  },
  categoryId: 0,
},
{
  expence: {
    amount: -43340.9,
  },
  categoryId: 12,
},]
```

Tried to combine different approaches from answers to similar but simpler cases already posted in the community but didn't managed to make them work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through each item in `array1`, then loop through each item in `array2` inside the loop and check whether the `categoryId` is equal to the `id`.

```js
const array1 = [{
    id: 8,
    name: 'Online Shopping',
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    name: 'Subscriptions',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Patreon donations',
  }
]
const array2 = [{
    expence: {
      amount: -66.66,
    },
    categoryId: 5,
  },
  {
    expence: {
      amount: 100018.85,
    },
    categoryId: 0,
  },
  {
    expence: {
      amount: -43340.9,
    },
    categoryId: 12,
  },
]

array1.forEach((e) => {
  array2.forEach((f) => {
    if (f.categoryId == e.id) {
      e.amount = f.expence.amount;
    }
  })
})
console.log(array1);
```

You can also make use of [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find the item where the `categoryId` is equal to the `id`:

```js
const array1 = [{
    id: 8,
    name: 'Online Shopping',
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    name: 'Subscriptions',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Patreon donations',
  }
]
const array2 = [{
    expence: {
      amount: -66.66,
    },
    categoryId: 5,
  },
  {
    expence: {
      amount: 100018.85,
    },
    categoryId: 0,
  },
  {
    expence: {
      amount: -43340.9,
    },
    categoryId: 12,
  },
]

array1.forEach((e) => {
  var arr = array2.filter(f => f.categoryId == e.id);
  if(arr.length > 0) e.amount = arr[0].expence.amount;
})
console.log(array1);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Spectric, both examples work perfectly in my case. Need to go back to JS fundamentals I suppose. Cheers.